# Instance of Generic as method parameter

Tags: java, class, generics

I am using generics in my class. *MyObject* must use T as an class, e.g.  new MyObject(Long.class). In the method *equal* I want to ensure that the argument given to the method is an instance of T.

`Object<T>` is not a valid Java Source, I know. 
I added it to the code example to show you what I mean, i.e. that value is an instance of T.

But what is the correct way to implement the equal method??

```
public class MyObject<T extends Class> {

    public boolean equal(Object<T> value) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you not overriding equals() (with an 's')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're *not* out to override `Object.equals(Object)`:

`T extends Class` makes scant sense because `Class` is final anyway, so the only thing `T` could be would be `Class<U>` for some `U`, and then you might as well let `U` be the type parameter. So what you might want it something like:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
  private Class<T> cl ;
  public MyClass(Class<T> cl) {
    this.cl = cl ;
    ...
  }
  public boolean equal(T value) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

and you then get to write, say, `new MyClass<Long>(Long.class)`.

But are you sure you need to store the `cl` parameter at runtime at all? Normally you would leave it out completely, so you just write `new MyClass<Long>()`.

Comment: Thats right. I used the type as generic and the class in the constructor... works fine. Thx

Answer (score 1):

If you're overriding the `equals()` method, then you *should* check the class of the object being used to compare equality with.

1. The signature will indicate that you can be passed any `Object`
2. equality can be defined between different object types (doesn't often happen, but it's valid)

If you're not overriding `equals()`, I would change your method name to be *distinct*. Otherwise life is going to be very confusing.

Comment: I recognized that naming the method "equal" wasnt a good idea. I do not want to override Object.equals()... My fault. Thx anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Assuming that you don't want to override equals`. I think you should do below

```
public class MyObject<T> {

    public boolean isEquals(T obj) {
        return false;
    };
}
```

There is no need of `Class` in your case as you are passing `Type` to `MyObject`

```
    MyObject<Long> myObject = new MyObject<Long>();
    myObject.isEquals(Long.valueOf(10);//It will only allow Long
    myObject.isEquals(10);             //Fails for int
```

References

1. [Generic Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)
2. [Lesson: Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)